# Magento 2 Get all the colors of a single Product?

Tags: magento2, color-swatches

How can I get all the available colors of a single product in Magento 2?

Comment: Is this simple product a configurable product or simple product? color is a dropdown attribute or multi-select attribute?

Comment: It is a configurable product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that you have configurable product object:

Then first you have to get it all child products ids  using

```
$childrenIds = $configurableProduct->getTypeInstance()->getChildrenIds($configurableProduct->getId());
```

**Then create a product collection and filter that collection by$childrenIds**

```
$productCollectionFactory->create()->addIdFilter($childrenIds);
 //Assume that your color attribute code is 'color'
$productCollectionFactory->addAttributeToSelect('color');
// optimized the collection
$productCollectionFactory->setPageSize(count($childrenIds))->setCurPage(1);   
$productCollectionFactory->groupByAttribute('color');

foreach($productCollectionFactory as $product){
    echo  $product->getData('color');
}
```

**Here** $productCollectionFactory is object of `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`

It's working fine.

Comment: Use `setPageSize` and `setCurPage` need to use for optimized the collection